# Parsing/Conversion issue in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting error while executing below query in sql server 2012:

```
DECLARE @Id NVARCHAR(max) = 2147483648

DECLARE @Result BIGINT = 0

IF (
    @Id = 0
    OR @Id = ''
    )

BEGIN

  SET @Result = NULL

END

ELSE

BEGIN

  SET @Result = convert(bigint,@id)

END
```

Output:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The conversion of the nvarchar
>   value '2147483648' overflowed an int column.

Can someone suggest me why it is happening ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `DECLARE @Id NVARCHAR(max) = '2147483648'`

Comment: and `IF (@Id = '0'OR @Id = '')` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting `0` to `bigint` will work because by default 0 will be treated as `INT`

```
DECLARE @Id NVARCHAR(max) = 2147483648
DECLARE @Result BIGINT = 0

IF ( @Id = cast(0 as bigint) -- or = '0'
      OR @Id = '' )
  BEGIN
      SET @Result = NULL
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      SET @Result = CONVERT(BIGINT, @id)
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `''` when setting `@id = '0'` in following:

```
DECLARE @Id NVARCHAR(max) = 2147483648

DECLARE @Result BIGINT = 0

IF (
    @Id = '0'
    OR @Id = ''
    )

BEGIN

  SET @Result = NULL

END

ELSE

BEGIN

  SET @Result = convert(bigint,@id)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compare `varchar` with `int`. `varchar` is converted to `int` before comparison.

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion,
>   an error is returned.

When `@ID` (`= '2147483648'`) converted to `int` it exceeds the max limit of `int`. hence you got the error;

> int
>   -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
>  4 Bytes

Solution:
Convert to both to `varchar`

```
IF (@Id = '0' OR @Id = '' )
```

Convert `@Id` to `bigint`.

```
IF ( convert(bigint, @Id) = 0 OR @Id = '' )
```